# C# comparing int and long as object

Tags: c#, .net, object, equality, equals-operator

If 2 variables of the type "object", which are Int32 and Int64, are compared, "true" is displayed in Visual Studio.
If I save this in a variable, it suddenly changes to "false".
I have already tried the EqualityComparer. The values remain unchanged.

```
int number1 = 2;
long number2 = 2;
object object1 = number1;
object object2 = number2;
var equals1 = number1 == number2; // true
var equals2 = object1 == object2; // object1 == object2 is true, equals2 is false
```

[image: screenshot]

Why is that?

EDIT:

[image: updated screenshot]

Comment: Simply, there's no easy way around this. When you do `int == long`, the **compiler** works out that there's a conversion from int to long, and inserts code to do this. When both sides are `object`, the compiler can't do this. There's nothing in the runtime which can take to integer types and figure out whether they can both be converted to a common type. If you know that one of the numbers is an int and the other is a long you can do this conversion yourself: `Convert.ToInt64(object1) == Convert.ToInt64(object2)`

Comment: I disagree with the dup because of the sentence "*I have already tried the EqualityCompare*" -- the `EqualityComparer` will already be doing what the answer in the dup says to do, and that doesn't work because OP's working with two boxed integer types which aren't necessarily the same type. Voting to re-open.

Comment: "*Hardcast to Int32 / Int64 would unfortunately not be an option.*" -- can you explain *why* not? Understanding this will help us suggest a suitable workaround

Comment: @canton7 I have updated the screenshot regarding EqualityComparer.
What confuses me is the fact that visual studio actually shows true when debugging if object1 and object2 are checked for equality.
I don't really want a hardcast because I don't want to check out all the different type-combinations. However, if there is no elegant solution to this, I would have to consider that.

Comment: @Servy, again, that question doesn't address the issue of the boxed integers being **different types**. That's about `<boxed int> == <boxed int>`, not `<boxed int> == <boxed long>`

Comment: @canton7 The OP choose to ask two separate questions.  One is answered by the duplicate, the other is unanswerable as they don't have enough information for anyone to answer it, as per your previous comment.  Such is the problem with asking multiple questions per post.  The OP now knows why this code behaves as it does.  If they want to formulate an answerable question about how to compare the objects that properly describes the actual situation in sufficient detail, then they can ask that question.

Comment: @syven I suspect you'll have to implement that logic I'm afraid -- it's normally done by the compiler, but that's not able to here because the types involved aren't known at compile-time. I don't know of anywhere in the runtime which implements that logic.

Comment: @Servy IMO the question is very clear that they're comparing a boxed int to a boxed long. Nothing in the linked dup addresses how to do that.

Comment: @canton7 If they're comparing a boxed int with a boxed long then they just cast them to those types and boom, done.  And they clearly know how to do that.  If they can't, it means there's something more complex going on preventing that, which we would need to know the specifics of to answer.  Again, you were the one asking for information about their problem and stating it's needed to provide a suitable solution.  Why now say the problem is clear and needs no information when the OP has provided no information in the meantime?

Comment: @Servy Right, they are asking two things: why doesn't `==` work, and how can it be fixed. The first part is addressed by the dup, but the dup doesn't address the second part -- and indeed, the answers in the dup say to do something which won't work in OP's case, and which OP has already effectively tried (through using `EqualityComparer<object>`). The second part requires some more info before we can suggest something sensible granted, but all of that is shut down if it's *closed* as a dup.

Comment: If we can't get the extra info, then sure, close it off as "not enough info". But IMO duping it at this point doesn't help anyone: it doesn't help OP find their solution, it doesn't help us answer OP (as we can't answer), and it doesn't help others who find this question with the same problem (as it won't have an answer, and the linked dup has misleading answers)

Comment: @canton7 The question being closed does not prevent it from being improved to no longer merit closure.  It being closed as too broad for asking multiple questions, or being closed as unclear because one of the questions is unclear, still results in the question being closed, and still allows the question to be edited to be a good question.  The first thing they need to do is edit it to not ask multiple questions for it to no longer merit closure.  Given that only one of the questions is currently answerable, leaving that one would be best.  They can ask their second question after fixing it.

Comment: @canton7 Questions that are not in an answerable state are *supposed* to be closed.  We don't *want* people posting answers to a question that does not have sufficient information to be given a quality answer.  We don't *want* people finding questions to answer if they're not in a state where they're ready to be answered (if they're looking for problematic questions hoping to fix them they can still do that).  The duplicate *does* have an answer to the one question that is actually answerable, making it useful.  More useful than closing it as unclear or broad without the one answer would be.

Comment: Use that unboxing on fly
var equals3 = (int)object1 == (long)object2; //true correct

Comment: I chose the variable type object because it should contain flexible values and these should be compared with one another. in order to hardcast you will need a check whether the object is also the respective type. and since an integer already has many different byte lengths, such a check would generate a long query. I spontaneously thought of a byte comparison, but this would only work with numbers. unfortunately i haven't found an elegant solution yet. the dub doesnt answer my question. @Servy

Comment: @syven As I said to canton.  You have asked multiple questions, which isn't appropriate for this site.  Of your two questions, one is answerable, and is answered by the duplicate.  The other doesn't have enough information for it to be answered, and so you first need to address that, and then ask a new question about how to solve that information that includes enough information and context for it to be answerable.  To be more specific, you'll need to indicate what the actual types of these objects actually can be, and how each of them need to be compared with each other type.

Comment: what actually interests me most is why visual studio while debugging can compare both objects and shows true as result but at runtime its false.

Comment: @servy will create a new question. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you implicitly boxed the variables into the heap, which create new references, which is why `equals2` is `false`.

Comment: You can use `Equals(object1, object2)` to protect against `null`, but that doesn't solve the problem, [see here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK4wD4AEBMBGAWAChiB7YAKwFMBjBAAgnoF568BuMy2h4F+gBQAbUjADmASg7FiWPAE4BAUQCOqCEIDOAiHHrAJE9kA===)

Comment: @canton7 right thats what `==` is doing but using the single arg version forces it to use the subtypes implementation.

Comment: I don't follow -- `Equals(object a, object b)` delegates to `a.Equals(b)` after null checks, [see here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Object.cs,53). That doesn't solve the problem that `Int32.Equals(object)` doesn't attempt to do the built-in numeric conversions that the compiler will do if you use `==` between two integer types

Comment: object1.Equals(object2) isnt solving my problem. [link](https://www.kara-dev.com/images/csharp-2.png)